# Facebook iOS9 Different Access Token

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook

After updating my project and respective pods for iOS9 and Swift 2.1, I've been dealing with a few oddities in the Facebook SDK.

I have upgraded to FBSDK 4.9.1 - tried, 4.9.0 and currently running 4.6.0. I have added all the new entries to the plist.

Now, I don't receive most of the common problems other users are having with the new SDK, and can't seem to find someone with a similar issue as mine.

The Facebook authorization process still opens and works on iPhone's 6 and higher it seems (running iOS9 and up)

However on devices such as an iPhone 5s (running iOS9 and up), the dialog shows up, yet the token given back to us from Facebook is different than it used to/should be/other versions of the app, and we use the FB token to authenticate into our app.

What could be missing or wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After sniffing the packets we realized now that Facebook uses the Safari Web View, instead of opening up via App, Facebook was using an old Cached Session from another account on Safari.

Silly mistake - but also an oddity with the new Facebook SDK.

Hope this helps someone else out.